# HTTPS stopped working with IIS express

Tags: asp.net, https, iis-express

I went through this whole procedure

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

a couple weeks ago and got https working on port 443 of all my IPs.  The machine was rebooted a few days ago and I tried accessing the site again today (launched via VS2010, IIS express tray shows site running on 80 and 443).  The http is working fine but https just says "internet explorer cannot display the page".  I can see with netstat that the system process is listening on port 443 but I don't get anything in the browser.  Fiddler shows some tunnel activity but nothing much else.  What should I check to get this back up and running?  All the steps on the above blog were voodoo to me so now that it's not working I don't really know where to start.

-JT

Comment: In case it's a useful clue, when I tried chrome the error is 101 connection refused... However, I can use putty and connect raw to port 443 and that connection succeeds fine.  I'm pretty lost here at the moment :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try the following (posted at the bottom of http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

> "I think by moving the self signed cert from Personal to Trusted Root
>   CA directory causes a problem that SSL stops working after developers
>   reboot their machines. (Don't know how it happens, but it does happen
>   consistently.) I finally get around this issue by export and re-import
>   the self-signed cert into the trusted root directory (instead of
>   simply drag it over). Now my self-signed cert is considered and I
>   don't need to REINSTALL/REPAIR IIS Express every time I reboot the
>   machine. "

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that... I'll give it a try.  I later narrowed it down the reboot being the issue so I am confident this will work for me too.

Comment: I experienced the same exact problem.  Thanks. Scott should really edit his suggestions other than putting a note.  I missed this detail after following his instructions precisely.

Comment: Wow, ya, that tutorial should be modified because that's a pretty big 'gotcha'.  It got me for a day and a half...

Comment: Note: you may need to restart Chrome for the cert to be recognized as trusted.

Answer (score 9):

for me problem was with **port number**: my Visual Studio 2013/IIS Express configured app port number was NOT in the range **:44300-:44398**

full answer about same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24957146/908936

Comment: Thank you for posting this! We screwed around for an hour and we were simply higher than the acceptable range! We were using 50000 and above.