# Debugging MVC application in VS2012 attempts to start IIS Express twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

**UPDATE**

I'm certain this is a Visual Studio bug with no obvious solution.  I've encountered a number of people who have the same exact issue.  I have submitted a bug ticket with Microsoft here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778864/vs2012-is-spawning-two-iisexpress-processes-when-attempting-to-debug

If you are having the same issue as described below, *please* go vote up the bug ticket so that it gets more attention.

---

Whenever I attempt to debug an MVC3 (or MVC4) application in Visual Studio 2012 configured to run on IIS express (version 8), I get the following error:

[image]

Here's the kicker: IIS Express *is* starting, even though Visual Studio doesn't think so and the debugger fails to attach.  The IIS Express tray opens and I can clearly see all configured websites are started:

[image]

Oddly enough, the IIS Express System Tray reports that there were some errors when running IIS Express.  Here's what it says:

[image]

This is a serious WTF.  It's reporting that 8080 is being used by an IIS Express Process - the one that was *just* started by Visual Studio.  So, Visual Studio is attempting to launch IIS twice, and when it predictably fails the second time, the debugger bails.  I should note that before launching the debug configuration in Visual Studio, I made *absolutely sure* no IIS Express processes were already running.  I used Process Monitor to verify that Visual Studio is in fact attempting to launch IIS Express twice:

[image]

Notice in the screen shot above you can clearly see websites running on IIS Express PID 4732.  PID 4924 is the second failed attempt at launching IIS Express.

This issue was initially occurring on a Windows 7 installation.  I reformatted completely, installed a fresh copy of VS2012, and got the same issue.  I went a step further and reformatted, installed Windows 8 and a fresh copy of VS2012, and the issue persists.

I have created brand new blank MVC3 and MVC4 projects.  *Nothing fixes it.*

I'm tearing out my hair here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed any extensions?

Comment: @w.brian, what happens if you switch back to cassini?

Comment: None.  I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.  Otherwise it is a completely vanilla installation.

Comment: @DaveA Cassini works fine, but I require IIS Express.

Comment: Understood. I prefer IIS Exp too. Looking for info to triangulate. Have you played with switching between dedicated and dynamic port? Have you recently upgraded VS (2012?)

Comment: Per my post, this issue is specific to visual 2012, and I have reformatted my computer twice, once with Windows 7, and now with Windows 8 in an attempt to resolve this issue.  These are very clean, vanilla installations.

Comment: Have you tried running IIS Express manually from the command-line?

Comment: Yes.  Running from the command line works just fine, as long as there isn't already an IIS Express process running.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? Have you tried uninstalling IIS Express and then install it again? I'd really try another distribution of Visual Studio. Either a trial or an Express version just to rule a lemon compilation of Visual Studio out.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 as specified in both the title and the body of the question...

Comment: There is several versions of Visual Studio 2012. See my updated comment above.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling IIS Express.  I have tried uninstalling Visual Studio 2012 and running before installing Update 1, and after installing Update 1.  Nothing works.

Comment: What media did you use to install Visual Studio 2012 then?

Comment: Over a file share with an enterprise license.

Comment: And have you tried uninstalling and using a different media, like a trial version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24639/discussion-between-oakninja-and-w-brian)

Comment: Late to the party here but have you verified that nothing else is accessing the port you're trying to use? `netstat -aon | find ":8080"` - you don't use Raven by any chance do you? Port 8080 is the standard port for RavenDB

Comment: Nothing is using the configured ports.  As I had mentioned, IIS Express starts successfully.  The issue is that Visual Studio attempts to launch it twice, and the debugger fails to connect when it fails the second time around.  Essentially,  IIS express starts, VS fails to attach and debug.

Comment: Are you running VS 2012 with administrator privileges

Comment: I've tried that.  Doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try a different media source, trial version etc? A clean version of Windows with a clean updated version of Visual Studio should really behave like everyone elses set up. Otherwise everyone would have this issue. Set up a Win8 VM and try a VS2012 trial there to avoid messing around.

Comment: Do you have anything special in the project properties page? Right-click the project > Web (tab) > Servers section or in the Build Events (tab) > pre-post-build event? Can you include the steps on how you configured the project to run on IIS Express?

Comment: The issue occurs with completely new, untouched MVC3 and MVC4 projects.  There are no pre or post build events.  When creating a MVC project in Visual Studio 2012, it is set by default to launch using IIS Express.

Comment: If IIS express is getting started for the first time, and you are able to browse the application, then why don't you attach to that process manually from VS debug option. That will help you to debug.

Comment: Because debug symbols do not get loaded when manually attaching to the IIS Express process.

Comment: @w.brian, The problem cannot be in IIS Express since you have re-formatted and re-installed. It must be in your Project or Solution. Do you have multiple projects in your solution?

Comment: @w.brian, also are you using virtual directories?

Comment: I have the exact same behavior on a fresh install of VS2012. Curiously, VS2010 also displays the same behavior on the same machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

w.Brian, I have followed this post since it's start and have had the exact same problem for quite a while now and I have just discovered what is causing the issue for me. I have been able to reproduce and fix the error for myself with this:

The reason VS2012 is starting iis express twice is related to being attached to a domain and being logged into a domain account. Once I logged into a completely local admin account I was able to launch and debug an MVC4 application without any issues. This is using Windows 8 Pro, VS2012 Update 1, attached to my domain, and no other software/extensions/configuration. Completely clean installation.

Comment: Dude, yes.  I am definitely having this issue on a domain but never considered that.  I will be able to verify this tomorrow.  I'll mark as answer if this is the problem and let Microsoft know on the bug ticket I opened.

Comment: You rock Epithanatios.  You were absolutely correct.  I will let Microsoft know.

Comment: Hi w.brian, would you be able to try a different domain account on your test machine? I have tried successfully to launch visual studio with my test machine with any other domain account except for mine. I'm almost at the point where I am going to ask to have my account wiped and a new one created. It seems to be related to how my account was setup but we are not sure what is different between mine and anyone elses.

Comment: Thanks @w.brain for doing this research. I too had this problem across installs and figured IISExpress was being launched twice. However, I don't want to have to run it with another domain account. Here's hoping that MSFT fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem now.  I've logged onto other DEV machines (where the devs do not have the problem) and seen the same error. They've come to my machine and successfully debugged the app. My I.T. is doing a deep dive into my domain user attributes, but we'll probably end up creating a new user. :(

Comment: Also interesting to note that the error happens regardless of whether or not IIS Express is already running. Sometimes the alert includes the complaint that the port is already in use. Most times it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Hi maybe this solutions could help you.

- Manage RuntimeVersion=”4.0″ to “4.0.30319″

Example:

```
<applicationPools>
<add name=”Clr4IntegratedAppPool” managedRuntimeVersion=”v4.0.30319″ managedPipelineMode=”Integrated”     CLRConfigFile=”%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config” autoStart=”true” /><br/><br/>
```

**reference:[Issue: Visual Studio 2012 > “Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server”](http://roykimsharepoint.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/issue-visual-studio-2012-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server/)**

- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to solve the issue
  **reference: [Debugging the “Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.” error from Visual Studio 2012.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/finbar_ryan/archive/2013/01/02/debugging-the-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-from-visual-studio-2012.aspx)**
- Try switching to the visual studio built in web host and run it.  After you run it once you should be able to switch back to iis express
  **reference: from the forum [Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](http://forums.asp.net/t/1793014.aspx/1)**
- try re-installing [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691), which contains iis-express.
- disable the logging module by modifying the applicationhost.config, which is located in the %userprofile%\documents\IISexpress\config directory. To do so you will need to comment out a couple lines in the file.

Under the / element, comment out the line

```
<add name="HttpLoggingModule" image="%IIS_BIN%\loghttp.dll" />
```

Under the // element, comment out the line

```
<add name="HttpLoggingModule" lockItem="true" />
```

After saving your changes try restarting iis express.

**reference: from stackoverflow forum: [Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171656/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)**

Comment: It worked for me. Simply switching to Visual Studio Build in Dev Web server and then running the app. Restarting then switching back to Local IIS Express.

Comment: Thanks for compiling these answers, as I've seen them scattered through various SO and Technet questions. None of them have worked for me either. Upvoted the bug at Connect.

Answer (score 4):

Right click you MVC project /*all of them one by one*/
go to properties
go to web tab
you must be having having checked "Use local IIS webserver" radio box
in the textbox below it make sure no to projects have the same port which in your case is `8080`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the answer here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1953087.aspx?VS+2013+Unable+to+launch+the+IIS+Express+Web+Server

It was strange behavior on a Windows 8 machine when 'bg' was part of the username

Comment: This worked for me as well. I also had to delete my existing iis express directory in order to get it to work.

Comment: Also look at this bug tickets:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/848945/visual-studio-2012-iis-express-fails-to-start-if-application-name-contains-bg
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/865116/process-with-an-id-of-id-is-not-running

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late to the party - here's my two pennies:

a) http://saintgimp.org/2012/05/03/fixing-the-error-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-failed-to-register-url-access-is-denied/

b) http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/20/unable-to-start-web-site-on-iis-process-can-not-access-the-file-because-its-being-used-by-another-process-how-to-resolve/

Synopsis: There is a URL reservation for the current port (usually Skype)

Comment: I feel like people are neglecting to read the original question.  This is *not* an issue with IIS Express not starting.  IIS Express *is* starting, but for some reason Visual Studio is attempting to start it *twice* and the debugger fails to connect.

Comment: @w.brian - Exactly what I get, no progress? Once I've closed the error dialog, I'm able to run the site from the IISExpress toolbar utility. But it's a pretty poor experience

Comment: @stupid-phil No progress.  I'm certain at this point it is a bug.  I have created a bug ticket with Microsoft here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778864/vs2012-is-spawning-two-iisexpress-processes-when-attempting-to-debug

I think the best bet to get this resolved is to vote up the ticket so that it gets some attention.

Comment: I have asked a question several times: Have you tried a different Visual Studio 2012 source, like the official trial version? @stupid-phil, what is your set-up?

Comment: I have an MSDN download of VS2012 Ultimate. Running on Win8 Pro

Comment: Just to rule some scenarios out: What version on IIS Express is installed? Have you tried reinstalling IIS Express by uninstalling in from add/remove programs and then reinstall using web platform installer? Have you reset your Visual Studio settings(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)? Have you tried creating a new Windows user with admin rights and tried debugging with that user just to rule out user setting errors? If this fails - try a Visual Studio Trial to rule out errors specific to your msdn source.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, do you have `127.0.0.1   localhost` defined in *folder*/system32/drivers/stc/hosts ? Otherwize, you can check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/finbar_ryan/archive/2013/01/02/debugging-the-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-from-visual-studio-2012.aspx), this might just be the key.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 using my domain account. In my case changing the Documents folder path (Right click on the Documents folder -> Properties -> Location) from *C:\Users\username\Documents* to *D:\Documents* helped

Comment: It seems you were plagued by the same problem as I. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This week, I experienced this identical issue: IIS Express starts, but VS complains it couldn't start  IIS Express and debugging fails.

I finally resolved the issue by applying the June 2014 hot-fix to IIS Express:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=43380

We (my IT support and I) found this hotfix after stumbling over and following a very unlikely problem.  Apparently, MS verified a bug in IISExpress 8.0 which results in it misbehaving if any part of the application name contains the letter combination "bg" (my username begins with bg):

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/848945/visual-studio-2012-iis-express-fails-to-start-if-application-name-contains-bg

Note: VS 2013 Update 4 already contains this fix, which may be why some people had success simply by updating to VS 2013.

Some other links we found concerning the issue (you may have to skim a bit to find the topic):

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1953087.aspx?VS+2013+Unable+to+launch+the+IIS+Express+Web+Server
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/865116/process-with-an-id-of-id-is-not-running

Answer (score 1):

What worked in my situation was to unload the project, then to edit the csproj file. I removed all sections regarding IIS and IISEXPRESS. Then I reloaded the project and chose USE IIS EXPRESS from the project properties all over again. It then worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an identical issue today (IISExpress trying to start twice and failing when hitting Debug in Visual Studio) while helping another developer with a web forms site.  After trying several solutions, we found that we could resolve the problem by:

- Creating a new, empty Visual Studio solution
- Adding an "Existing Website" pointing to a new, empty folder
- Copying the contents of the existing (non-working) website into the new folder we created

Simply removing and re-adding the website to the original solution did not work, nor did creating a new solution and adding back the existing site.  I can start IISExpress from the command line just fine.

After doing a before-and-after comparison of the .SLN files I believe that is where the problem lies.  Since I had found a workaround I didn't spend a lot of extra time on it.  Obviously recreating the entire solution from scratch may not be an option for larger projects (ours was a very small one) but hopefully this at least points in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are two instances of the site `FrontEnd` running of course, but notice that one instance is HTTP and the other HTTP**S**.

It's possible to get two instances when `SSL Enabled` is set to *True* in the web site properties but the `Project Url` on the *Web* tab is set to an HTTP address.

Make them both HTTP (or HTTPS) and that might fix it.