# Working sample of ThinkTecture IdentityServer with SelfHost working on https?

Tags: https, requiressl

Is there a working example of ThinkTecture IdentityServer with SelfHost working on https?

I searched samples in the project itself and in separate project for samples

- https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3
- https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3.Samples

All I found included `RequireSsl = false` in `IdentityServerOptions`, and precofigured urls to http (e.g. http://loсalhost:3333/core. Any attempt to change it to https leads to `IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from...`

What I need is working example or instructions, how to change any of that samples to run under https. We can suppose that any client in the sample has been already configured to https, if it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have IIS Express Development Certificate it's used for localhost bindings.

If not use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-fix-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate) to restore it.

Then you can use cmd: **netsh http show sslcert** to check **ipport** bindings and add new if needed.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: IIS express manipulation are not applicable here. SelfHost sample seems to be using its own http implementation. Although, cannot find a way to make it working wuth SSL option turned on.

Comment: Actually i have no problems with running theirs samples.
I tried latest SelfHost (Minimal) which is listening on: https://localhost:44333/core

Comment: @moudrick 
Basically Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener is responsible for self hosting.

And you need to configure SSL for the HttpListener.

[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support) is the sample how to do such configuration.