# Error cannot connect to local host visual studio professional 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a project in Visual Studio Professional 2013, I have been working on this project previously on VS web 2015. A while ago VS stopped being able to run projects on all of my internet browsers including brand new or blank projects that I just created. Whenever I run the code the same error pops up "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" on a localhost connection. VS's consul says: "The program '[9640] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003)."  I have already tried deleting the iisexpress.exe folder from my documents and from the projects folder so that it could rebuild, but that did not work. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled my VS software, so I dont think that it is the problem. I looked through my firewall and I don't believe that it is the problem. I did a ton of searching the web for a way to fix the issue and found that this is commonly caused because nothing is listening on the IP:Port you are trying to connect to. So I ran:

```
netstat -na
```

in my cmd prompt. I found there was no TCP (or UDP) connection listening on the port I am trying to use "56239". I am not sure how to make my computer listen on this port. I am trying to finish up this project that I have been working on for a while now and would like to be able to run the site on my local host. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have look here, have you installed Fiddler?, this can help diagnosing, and changing the port number may work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190881/how-to-solve-err-connection-refused-when-trying-to-connect-to-localhost-running

Comment: @Nick, do you repair your repair the IIS Express from the control panel? please check that whether it is related to the "IIS Express Development Certificate" in your side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869246/iisexpress-cannot-find-ssl-page-running-localhost-with-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I ended up doing a system restore on my desktop and it works fine now