# HTTPS not starting in IIS when viewed from tray

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I was working happily on my project. Then came a need to enable access to the server from remote machine (android) in LAN. I followed few answers on `StackOverflow` and they have completely ruined my project.

- [How to enable external request in IIS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/how-to-enable-external-request-in-iis-express)
- [IISExpress returns a 503 error from remote machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442551/iisexpress-returns-a-503-error-from-remote-machines)
- [localhost refused to connect Error in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio)

Earlier when I used to `Debug` using Visual Studio, I used to see two URLs, but I now I only see one. The debugging used to start in `https://localhost:44373` but now https is just not starting and I get connection refused when I browse the `https` link. `http` link works fine.

[image]

I even tried to reset by following methods,

- Deleted `.vs\<project>\config\applicationConfig`
- Deleted IIS configuration `rmdir /s /q "%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress"`

but none helped i.e. `https` is not starting even after using doing this as well

`IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:44373/ -UseSelfSigned`

**Please help. I am getting worried. My basic intent is to enable `HTTPS` and enable access to this `https` from remote machine.**

If someone knows about good server where I can deploy website and easily do this, you may suggest as an alternative, but suggest a solution to current problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio.

Following this link to [Remove your IIS Development Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28890205/3722884).

Now, [Repair IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-restore-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate) from control panel.

Start Visual Studio. Things will start to work