# IIS Express Debugging with SSL Issues

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, ssl-certificate, iis-express

I have a vanilla MVC project that I am attempting to run using HTTPS. I am getting an error back from Chrome to the effect of "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". I have "SSL Enabled" set to true and when I debug the application, the project URL set to https://localhost:44333/ does load in the browser window as expected.

I have spent almost 2 days trying to figure this issue out to no avail. I have uninstalled IIS Express 10 twice, repaired Visual Studio 2015, and followed directions on various blog posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress).

I have looked in my certmgr.msc too and I cannot find a localhost Trusted Root Certificate Authority under "Trusted Root Certificate Authority > Certificates" either. I am not sure if there is suppossed to be a cert there or not but I thought that info might be helpful to anyone that can point me in the right direction.

Any ideas on what could be going on?

- Windows 7
- IIS 10.0 Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had two IIS Express Certificates installed. I followed the following thread that helped me solve the issue I was having...

[How do I fix a missing IIS Express SSL Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-fix-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the cause was a certificate installed on machine level (which makes sense) and not for my user. I had to run MMC as administrator to delete them from the personal store (localMachine).

After that repairing IIS sorted the problems.