# After installing VS 2015 Update 3, sending HTTPS request to WebAPI development IIS Express causes SocketException

Tags: asp.net-web-api, https, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have a Desktop client making HTTPS requests to a WebServer hosted in Visual Studio IIS Express environment. I have been developing using VS 2015 Update 2 for several months and things have worked without issues.

However, yesterday I installed VS 2015 Update 3.
First I had to install the locally issued SSL certificate on my computer (I'm fairly certain I didn't have to do this with Update 2). But once that was out of the way, things were working fine.

When I turned on my machine today and loaded my development environment, I get the following chain of exceptions when sending the HTTPS request:

> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An Unexpected
> error occurred on a send.
>
> IOException: Unable to read data from the
> transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
> the remote host.
>
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host

I have not made any other changes to my dev environment except upgrading Resharper from 9.2 to 2016.1, but I can't imagine that having anything to do with my issues.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing my issues?

**Update:**

I don't get the Exceptions if I don't use SSL. So is seems to be some change to the IIS Express used by Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 which causes some SSL issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that my problem was caused by an incorrect approach to adding the new IIS Express 10.0 self signed SSL certificate as a trusted certificate.

Following "Resolution Number #1" in this blog post solved it for me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about IIS Express, but I experienced the same issue on IIS. It turned out that the certificate was unlinked from the https bindings during Update 3 installation, and I had to reenable it by choosing IIS Express Development Certificate.

[Another answer may perhaps lead you in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-fix-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate) concerning IIS Express.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the Update 3-installation did something with the SSL certificate. I tried the approach in your link, and after I used a different approach to trusting the certificate created by IIS, I got things working again. I have posted an answer with a link to the trust procedure. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and fixed it by Repairing the IIS Express 10.0 in Program and Features (or Add/Remove Programs).