# Visual studio 2017 "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'"

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

If I attempt to launch my .net core app I get this message. I realize there are many posts out there claiming to fix this but I have tried every method they suggest and none are working.

If I go into the project properties under debug and change the port, then it will connect 1 time. Then if I attempt to connect again, it will give me the same error again. I can then switch the port back to the original and it will load one time, then it will fail any time beyond that, until I switch it again. Anyone have any ideas or fixes they used?

Thanks!

Comment: A friend suggested not using IISexpress which has circumvented the problem.

Comment: Restarting VS 2017 and deleting the hidden folder .vs in the root folder solved this for me.

Comment: People usually have no idea what are the settings, so they have no easy way to tell what's up. Try to use Jexus Manager to see what's up and then the solution can be clear, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I installed core 2.0 and updated VS 2017 to 15.4.3 today, had the same error.

I ended up changing the application to run on a different port, it worked for me.

I have tried to delete the vs folder but did not work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Something for me. All ok after change the port on project settings.

Comment: Sometimes you need to change the port directly in applicationhost.config file

Comment: I can't believed that worked, but I'm not complaining.

Comment: I got the issue when I have copied the solution from one machine to another one. I have deleted "vs" folder that worked for me.

Comment: I got the same issue with my solution at some point, but apparently I needed to run VS as Administrator for it to work (maybe clearing the .vs folder would have worked for me as well, but I did not get there)

Comment: I got this error today after updating my VS2019 to 16.6.2. Worked by changing the port as mentioned here.. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, It worked for me, After change the port. Thank you

Answer (score 78):

I had this problem. There is  a hidden folder in directory of project that name is '.vs'. Close the Visual Studio and delete this folder. The problem will be solved.

Comment: Worked for me as well!! Thank you

Comment: Yes this too worked for me. People should try this solution first if they stumble across such an issue.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me, and I tried many.

Comment: It's amazing how many times just deleting that folder fixes issues like this.  Confirming that this fixed this for me in VS2019 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 24):

I know there is already an accepted answer to this question, but none of the solutions worked for me and my solution may help someone. I am using **VS2017** with an **ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages** project.

The error just started appearing for no obvious reason, and I tried the solutions posted here.

I ran the web app from the command line using the *dotnet run* command to see if that would bring up any meaningful errors, and there was a warning about the URL not being correctly bound. I looked in my projects **Properties\launchSettings.json** file and noticed that the **applicationUrl** properties were different.

[image]

1. Change the values for **applicationURL** so they are the same
2. Close the project and close VS
3. Delete the hidden .vs folder (as mentioned in the accepted answer)
4. Start up VS as Admin

Your app should work fine.

Comment: No clue why, but for me it started working when setting
iisSettings > iisExpress > applicationUrl to port 5000 ("http:// localhost:5000")
Anyways, thanks for your hint! :)

Comment: You are probably getting access denied because the port is reserved possibly as an url acl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990108/2004532

Comment: For me it all started when I ran application without debugging option (Ctrl + F5).

Answer (score 9):

I was having this issue with Visual Studio 2019 with a clean branch from  master. Restarting the PC solved the problem.

My colleague said he is having the problem about 2 times a month and other tries for solutions did not work.

Comment: I tried some of the other suggestions but with no luck. Then I suddenly got an error message (after doing a "clean" I think) claiming a file was locked (in use by another process). I restarted my computer and then it worked again.

Answer (score 4):

It could also just be that there are iisexpress.exe processes hanging around in task manager which were running on the same port.

I've just found a couple and killing them solved this problem for me without needing to delete any .vs folder or changing ports or anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

I gave up, and chose to run the project as self hosted, instead of 'IIS Express' in the play/run drop-down box.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was caused by the port for HTTP and HTTPS being the same:

[image]

The ports must be different:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 3):

In a solution if you have multiple projects using ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2017 and you are trying to use the same port number you will get this error. You must have unique port assignment in your solution.

Go here in your project: Properties/launchSettings.json open this file and edit the port numbers here. Note: This is where you change the SSL port (two places).

Reason: VS/IIS Express maintains bindings to all the ASP.NET Core projects in your solution that use IIS Express as the server. For example if you use Kestrel or some other server you will not have this problem. VS creates a new port for each app when it is created in the solution to ensure you do not have port conflicts.

If you are trying to use Azure AD registered applications reply ports and trying to "reuse" your app registration, you might think to simply change the "app's" port so that you don't have to register it in Azure; this will not work. If you are just testing apps and want to reuse a registration then you must make sure that the app you are currently working on is the ONLY one on the port - manually. If you need to test two or more apps then you must register them in Azure AD individually as you would in production.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me and it is really simple:

1. Right-click project
2. Properties
3. Debug
4. App URL: change port to 5000

Done, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Changin https -> http in my applicationUrl solved this issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by 
adding exclusion to file devenv.exe in windows defender (anti virus, Win10)

how to know this is the issue;
when you load project defender will notify in notification unauthorized changes blocked. if this is the issue just add the exception as above mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. In my case Windows Defender didn't block first instance of VS, but if I wanted to run two projects (two separate VS windows) the second one hanged...

Answer (score 1):

For me above solutions did not work

But changing the `IIS Express Bitness` to `x64` worked

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue. Running VS in admin mode solved this issue for me.

Comment: You are probably getting access denied because the port is reserved possibly as an url acl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990108/2004532

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties - select debug tab - change the App URL - e.g. to http://localhost:57520/

Something else can be running on your port that interferes.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

For me with VS2019, faced this same issue on start running our project.
So **right clicking on IIS Express** icon in notification pane near by DateTime pane in our laptop/Desktop. It will show up all running application, at last can find Exit. **Click Exit** there and run your project should work. That worked for me, without closing VS19 project.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with `netsh` configuration trying to make the server accessible from outside, I added a new `iplisten` entry. The IISExpress showed the error ***Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'*** which was fixed after deleting the iplisten entry using:

`netsh http delete iplisten <ip-address>`

You can view the current list of iplisten entries using

`netsh http show iplisten`

They require running an elevated (administrator) command prompt.

It seems like IISExpress has no error message in this a case.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're hard-coding a specific IP address (not localhost), check that it hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all. didn't work above.
changing host in applicationhost.config fixed.

change localhost to 127.0.0.1

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50740:127.0.0.1" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44381:127.0.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It works after I reenter username and password for the application pool's identity account

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Enable SSL" to false in project properties\Debug section worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may not completely direct your case, but I just had to restart my (windows) system. The [diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50507657/182542) of @Turneye may very well be the reason and his solution might accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I added the localhost option on the applicationhost.config file and run visual studio as administrator and it worked for me.

```
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6873:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44320:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6873:192.168.137.1" />
```

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't have to run Visual Studio as an administrator or with administrative rights. It creates options for malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

Some times running visual studio as administrator solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked by changing the applicationUrl in launchsettings.json file to different port number and that url to be same for all places inside this file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (VS 2019), all I have to do is Rebuild the code before I re-run the app after each code modification.

P.S.  I am coding server-side Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used `netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:<port>/ user=everyone` to add a specific url acl using the problem port then you'll need to delete it with `netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:<port>/ user=everyone`.

Another solution is to run Visual Studio as an administrator which allows it to override the urlacl.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue multiple times in VS2019, then I realized when I make small edits and restart the IIS Express this problem is more pronounced. Some of the discussion above about ports make me think since I was closing the app by just closing the browser. So I believe the port was not released and it failed the start next time around.
I started closing the debug by clicking the "Stop Debugging" button in the VS2019. The issue didn't occur again for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by restart my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the solution fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using .Net Core 3.x and still struggling, like myself, I finally after days of searching found a hint to the problem https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jan/14/ASPNET-Core-IIS-InProcess-Hosting-Issues-in-NET-Core-31.

> In .NET Core 3.x InProcess hosting for IIS is the default. OutOfProcess hosting externally runs Kestrel.exe and has IIS proxying requests into the external Kestrel HTTP host. InProcess hosting uses a custom IIS Module that bootstraps a custom .NET Core host right into the IIS host process which provides better performance and a smaller footprint.

Changing to "Out of Process" (Right Click Project > Properties > Debug > Web Server Settings > Hosting Model), closing visual studio, deleting the hidden .vs folder (as described in previous comments), and then running IIS Express in VS *finally* worked. If you ever change it back to "In Process" for testing and it doesn't work, you'll have to delete the .vs folder again after you change it back and close the project.

---

If you're like me and that got you over one hurdle and into another....

My next issue was i was getting this error `This webpage is not available (with error code "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET")` when running a request to ping the server in powershell (`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri:https://localhost:{port}/{endpoint}`). [This thread mentioning the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092378/after-installing-vs-2015-update-3-sending-https-request-to-webapi-development-i) lead me to [a thread that mentioned a missing iss express development cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036984/how-do-i-restore-a-missing-iis-express-ssl-certificate), which mentions solving it by running `./IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:{port}/ -UseSelfSigned` in the IIS Express program files directory in an admin powershell terminal.

---

I'm also gonna post my first issue here when trying to run IIS Express from Visual Studio, which was `Cannot find C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisepxress.exe`. IIS Express was for some reason installed not only in my `Program Files (x86)`, but in my second drive (`D:\Program Files (x86)`). After realizing that there is just no way to change where Visual Studio is looking for IIS Express (even though it's also installed on the D drive), I uninstalled IIS Express (which is probably how my dev cert got removed), [in RegEdit changed my Program Files directory back to the "C\Program Files" folder](https://www.itechtics.com/change-default-installation-folder-windows-10/) (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion > ProgramFilesDir key), and [reinstalled IIS Express from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48264).

---

Finally, I can run my .Net Core API locally using IIS Express.

Good luck all!

Answer (score 0):

Your port is blocked for that specific user. Either change the port or user, or otherwise allow that port for that user. Admins usually have all the rights.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason is that port is used by other application or system. Follow the steps to identify the port issue.

1. You need to verify that the port is available or not.

   - replace your port number in the command and fire this in administrative command prompt or in any other shell. i.e.  I was using 1344 port.

> **netstat -ano -p tcp |find "1344"**

[image]
It will print the information if any process use the given port.
you will get process id (PID) in last column of the above command's result

2. Go to Task Manager -> Details Tab -> check the process by Id ( add the PID column if it's not visible )

[image]

3. As the port is occupied by a system process, we should change the port in our project.

   else if it is other program, you may kill the process or change the port in that program if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Delete IISExpress Logs of the solution under path C:\Users[user name]\Documents\IISExpress\Logs and start running the project it worked fine.

Deleting .vs folder didn't work for me, neither the updates