# Re-Installing Visual Studio 2017 Localhost Certificate

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2017

Sometime in the process of installing VS2017 (or maybe later), the program installs a certificate for local development.

Everything worked fine until I installed Fiddler and since that moment the VS2017 certificate stopped working and I get the "Your connection is not private" message whenever I navigate to my localhost app.

Any ideas how to re-install the original certificate so that my localhost becomes again a trusted host?

Answer (score 5):

Type “manage computer certificates” into the win10 search box. Navigate to Personal/Certificates:
[image]

Verify you have exactly one localhost cert. If you have more than one, delete all but the most current.  If you have one but localhost is not trusted, delete it. Visual Studio will prompt you to install a new cert when localhost uses HTTPS, not when you install VS2017.

It's unlikely Fiddler had anything to do with this problem.

Comment: If you delete the certificate and aren't being prompted to recreate it, you can fix that by repairing IIS Express per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048613/5

Note that you only see the repair option in the Control Panel's Add / Remove, not the modern settings.