# Angular : Lazy arising of certificate problem, and difficulties to solve it

Tags: angular, certificate

I have executed the two first chapters of Google's Tour of Heroes, 21 times.
There was some stuff to do, but everything ran fine (except three copies lost a reference, but I shall open another thread).
When I try to execute it a 22nd time on the same machine, with the same Visual Studio, I am said that I cannot execute this project, as no valid certificate is installed.
At this step, a question already arises : who is one laughing at?
And I have a very unpleasant assumption on this topic.

Well never mind, as the automatic creation of the certificate is proposed, I run Visual Studio with elevation of privileges, when the message proposing to automatically create the certificate arises I click on OK, and then I wait for the list of heroes. Hum, not really as I am starting a new project, but at least the text "heroes work".
Instead of this, I am said that no valid certificate is installed, and so ... I have got to go to the other queue : "something to declare".
And let me tell you, the customs are not in a hurry.
From the start menu I search CMD.EXE, to launch it as administrator.
I use the CD command to select the src\app folder of the project.
Then I type
`dotnet dev-certs https --trust`
I read the message telling me that I have got to verify the origin of this certificate (no idea of it, do you?), pay attention that it can be dangerous, and then I click on OK.
On the command line window I see the console saying "Successfully created and trusted a HTTPS certificate."

It is nice, that it is successful, is not it?

I launch the project again, and I get the same message.

In the folder of the Firefox program, I create a "distribution" sub-folder, and there I create a policies.json file, that contains

> {
> "policies": {
> "Certificates": {
> "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true
> }
> }
> }

I launch the program again, and I get the same message.

In Firefox I went to about:config, and saw that security.enterprise_roots.enabled is locked on true.

I tried something with openssl but did not find the program.

Hum ... Perhaps at this step I can do a pause, cannot I?
Do you think I did anything wrong?

Oh, a message during posting asks me what I tried.
Do not you think that it is the essential contents of my message?
And I also said what I expected: that the compilation goes further, and that Firefox displays me "heroes work".
It did that 21 times, but this time no.

Some information I do not have to forget:

- Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.22621.2428] - Windows 11 22H2
- E-Set Internet Security 16.2.15.0
- Visual Studio 2022 Community 17.7.5
- Node v18.18.0
  / Oh, and when trying to tell you the version of Angular (that is not the one that was presented last week) I realise that the projects that were OK get the same error. So, I had a certificate that expired yesterday night.
  I should incline to say it does not matter, to install a new one, does it?

Still another precision: I re-tested the project after restarting the machine, in case the certificate is only recognised during the following session.

---

In certmgr, I have 9 certificates delivered to localhost on 9th Nov. 2023, valid until 8th Nov. 2024. That must be approximately the number of attempts I did.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem, thanks to this thread:
[Setting up SSL certificate in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811355/setting-up-ssl-certificate-in-visual-studio)

I did not repair IIS, not even sure I have it installed, but my assumption that having an old certificate in the base was not a problem, was false. At a moment I tried to suppress the ones I saw, but there were still others.

After that, I still got a problem, but after closing the tab that showed the message about the certificate, I saw this time it was an error 80070003 when launching InteropServices. So, I launched a search on this error number, and saw I had to launch Visual Studio as administrator.

The application compiles, and shows the heroes.