# Visual Studio 2019: "This site can’t provide a secure connection" on localhost

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, localhost, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I've installed Visual Studio 2019 and uninstalled Visual Studio 2017.

Now if I start an ASP.NET (Core) site with https, it always say on Chrome:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection

or on Edge

> Can’t connect securely to this page

#### Screenshots:

Chrome:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

The URLs are correct. This also the same http://localhost:56784/ (it redirects to https)

[image]

### Tried

What I've tried:

- Updated Visual Studio 2019
- Create a new ASP.NET Core 2 website
- Tested with a ASP.NET site (non core)
- Remove IIS certificates with MMC
- Checking/changing the IIS settings in Visual Studio 2019 (project properties with context menu and project properties with F4)
- Searching on Stackoverflow & Google ;)
- Repair Visual Studio 2019

### Issue

I think the issue is introduced by:

- Installing Visual Studio 2019  and/or,
- Uninstalling Visual Studio 2017  and/or,
- Updating Windows 10 (current Version: 10.0.18362 Build 18362)

The underlining issue looks like a wrong/old/not supported TLS version?

### Question

What can I do to diagnose/fix the problem?

Comment: Does this help [Developing locally with ASP.NET Core under HTTPS, SSL, and Self-Signed Certs](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx)? Try running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`.

Comment: Check the certificate mappings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html and make sure they point to the right certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` didn't work unfortunately. Also I don't think this is a certificate issue. I can't see even the certificate in browser as the connection is reset before the certificate is send.

Comment: I've repaired Visual Studio 2019, lost all my extensions installs, and still the same issue is there :'(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Repair of IIS Express fixed my problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for having saved my life!

Comment: I have both VS2017 and VS2019, and I have OP's same problem with VS20129. I can't repair IIS Express 10, because my installed version is more recent than the version I downloaded from MS.  :-P  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting error in repairing IIS..its like looking for a file..

Comment: What does the image said?  All of the images are being blocked at my employer's building due to security risk, like virus for example.   

So what does the image said?  Thanks

Answer (score 36):

Just as it did not work for `@Nosnetrom` -  repairing IIS 10.0 Express did not work for me either. As `@Julian` mentioned my problem was caused by uninstalling VS 2017 as well.

This is **what did not work** for me:

- uninstalling / re-installing VS 2019
- installing VS 2017
- uninstalling / re-installing / repairing IIS 10.0 Express

This is **what worked** for me:

- after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38094929/7191056) advice - I realized that I was using port 51542 instead of a port in the range of 44300 through 44399
  [image]
- then I updated the **applicationhost.config** file according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges#using-ssl) advice. The location of said file on my Windows 10 machine is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config`. I had to open that file in Notepad ran as an administrator otherwise I could not save these changes:
  [image]
- then in Visual Studio I created a new **virtual directory**
  [image]
- that seemed to have done the trick for me - when I ran the application it worked
  [image]

Comment: Give this man a medal!  This is the only thing that worked for me  VS2019 Community on a new machine.

Comment: what if I'm using swagger? will this approach work? I'm having issue since swagger is using http protocol..

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution.  This saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: This worked for me running an older ASP.NET app in VS2022.  In a more modern .NET Core MVC app, I simply had to enable SSL.

Answer (score 9):

For those who all the above methods didn't worked:

open a command prompt and then run:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

and then:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the above solutions worked for me, Following steps worked for me.
Go to chrome or edge browser and type `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
search for localhost in query domain, you will find lists of domain including localhost. Now delete the domain
[image]

Delete the domain by typing localhost
[image]

Comment: But then you will use http instead of https after this step?

Answer (score 4):

Just follow below steps:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete `.vs` folder
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. Build and Run the Application

As per my understanding, `.vs` folder keeps the old settings inside the `applicationhost.config` file. So better to delete all cached settings and start with fresh.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem as follows;

1. run the web project in debug mode on Visual studio 2019.
2. if it's on chrome you should do this ;
   [image: Empty cache and hard reload]

Comment: What do you mean with "reload permanent deletion"?

Comment: I mean, Empty Cache and Hard Reload

Answer (score 2):

None of this worked for me. What did work (and it's not as drastic as the other answers)...

Go into web project and set Start URL and Project URL to this: https://localhost:44365/

Save (but don't run the Project).

Edit .vs/[ProjectName]/config/applicationhost.config and change the bindings for the web project to this:

```xml
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44365:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53269:localhost" />
```

Reopen Visual Studio and when I started the website it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case use SSL check box was gone in debug section of project properties. everything was fixed by checking again

Comment: is this the same answer as from Bashar Abu Shamaa /  Mar 22 2021 at 14:52? Please update that one!

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure how it got unchecked, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, select Properties, 'Debug', check the checkbox "Enable SSL", that's it, worked with me by doing this

Answer (score 0):

If you 'are using services.AddHttpsRedirection like

```cs
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = Configuration.GetValue<int?>("https_port", null);
});
```

Make sure **HttpsPort** is null or a valid port in **appsettings.json** or **appsettings.Development.json** file.

Answer (score -2):

Clear your browser history and cookie

Comment: This is just guessing. A Secure connection (TLS) is on the presentation layer (or lower), and http (cookie) a least a layer higher, on the application layer. See [OSI model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)