# Was trying to set up Swagger for my .net core 7.0 project but it gives "Fetch error NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" on opening

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Most of the controllers have custom routing and APIs work when I fetch them through postman

Also have added the following for Swagger in my *Startup.cs*

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "ToDo API",
                Description = "An ASP.NET Core Web API for managing ToDo items",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "Example Contact",
                    Url = new Uri("https://example.com/contact")
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "Example License",
                    Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
                }
            });
        });
```

Also

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
                options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

        }
```

The web page loads but the APIs do not
[image: webpage]

After Inspecting the URL
[image: URL]

The Logs

```
2023-05-17 12:44:14.5197 Error Error parsing layout aspnet-request-statuscode will be ignored. Exception: System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-request-statuscode'. Is NLog.Web not included?
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String itemName)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.GetLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, String name, Nullable`1 throwConfigExceptions)
```

Already have the following in my *nlog.config*

```
  <extensions>
<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/></extensions>
```

Comment: Copy the URL and paste it into the address bar. It will show you the exception. What does the exception say?

Comment: Just loads for a long time and does not return anything, just like the web page. In the inspect it says "NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Added another image for clarity

Comment: What happens if you put RoutePrefix = "swagger";?

Comment: Nothing, same error. Just loads for a long time.

Comment: Have you tried running "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" in the dev console? More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291876/how-to-force-visual-studio-to-re-create-the-ssl-certificate-for-a-net-core-web

Comment: `NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that the API's web server isn't accepting requests. At this point, your actions are probably more relevant than the code. For example, if you start debugging and then drag the tab into another window, that terminates the underlying browser process and creates another (how tab isolation works). Visual Studio sees the original browser process die, stops the server process, and ends the debugging session. So you'll need to describe your entire process in order to see where it's breaking down.

Comment: @b166er does not effect anything

Comment: @madreflection Nothing, I start the project, it opens up the default page in the firefox, I write swagger URL in the browser and then it opens the swagger page where the loading screen never ends and results in the above uploaded error

Comment: Tried to check the logs and got some nlog error which I just edited in my post

Comment: Nevermind, that log error has nothing to do with Swagger not working

Comment: Does the server at `localhost:5001` actually use HTTPS? Or is it supposed to be accessed over plain HTTP?

Comment: @Helen tried changing the httpredirection but nothing work. Then I removed all the controllers and added a dummy one and it loaded

Comment: This might be encounter because of incorrect defination within controller action or attributes. Please check that first. In addition to this, also check your CORS configuration.

Comment: Nvm I fixed it, apparently it was because they had a few non actions inside the some of the controllers which caused this, fixed this by adding "    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]" on top of the non action methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, apparently it was because I had a few non-action methods inside the some of the controllers which caused this, fixed this by adding `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` on top of the non action methods.