# How would i create a SSLStream using a self-signed certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, c#-7.0

I am trying to set up a secured connection using SSL in C# (7.0). I've found the SSL stream class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-7.0). Using the example above i've written a ssl server/client. The problem is, that I could not figure out, how to verify a self-signed certificate (or a certificate signed using a self-signed CA/root certificate) on the client.

My current attempt:
I am creating a self-sigend CA certificate using XCA. Further i create a server certificate using the create CA. I exported both certificates as PKCS # 12 (the private key of the CA is included in the client certificate, i know that this is a security problem, i'll change it later).

On the server, i am just calling `sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer` with the certificate as a parameter.
On the client, i am using the following code (the X509 certificate is the self-signed root certificate):

```
    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
        object sender,
        X509Certificate? certificate,
        X509Chain? chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (certificate == null || chain == null)
            return false;
    
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("...", "...");
        chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(cert);
        chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
        return chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
    }
    
    public static void RunClient(string machineName, string serverName)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
    
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(),
            false,
            ValidateServerCertificate,
            null
        );
    
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
    
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Client closed.");
    }
```

I am getting the following error message: "The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback."
The certificate chain has two status items: NotSignatureValid, UntrustedRoot

I have already tried/checked:

- Returning true in ValidateServerCertificate -> the connection is built successfully
- I've validated, that the certificate parameter in ValidateServerCertificate is actually the same certificate as loaded on the server
- I've tried using a self-signed certificate/a custom root CA certificate
- I've tried multiple fiile formats for the CA certificate
- I've tried to install the root certificate in my windows certificate store

Am i missing something? Or is something wrong with my certificates?

Comment: Try to created and trusted a HTTPS certificate like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75264823/7247051

Comment: The error message says "remote certificate".  The validation of the certificate is usually done by making a virtual connection on same machine. A service is started to make the connection. It is working on the server. On the client what machine are you using to make the virtual connection?  Is a listener started on the machine?  On your link read the purple note : If the application that creates the SslStream object runs with the credentials of a Normal user, the application will not be able to access certificates installed in the local machine store unless permission has been explicitly given

Comment: The suggestion by Ihdina works, thanks! jdweng, what do you mean with "a virtual connection on same machine"? What service is startet and why or how should it be working on the server? What machine or what type of machine should i be using for making the virtual connection? The client is not starting any listeners
Ok the permissions might be the cause of the problem

Comment: But how exactly would i configure the application to be able to access to local certificate store?

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do. Are you expecting the client to validate any possible CA, even one it doesn't trust? Or are you expecting to pin a particular CA certificate so that it can trust it in some way?

Comment: Also `NotSignatureValid` implies there is something wrong with the cert. Have you checked the certificate chain with another method?

Comment: I am trying to configure my ssl client so that it trusts a specific CA certificate
I didn't check the chain with another method, i'll try that out

Comment: Maybe you should just import the CA cert into the client's trust store (either user or machine level)