# Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm constantly getting this error in rails server log:

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faye-websocket-0.7.2/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:44:in `receive_data'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    /home/budkin/gamestown/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

everything works fine, but the errors are just annoying

Yes, this is on `thin`

Comment: Isn't that on a `thin` webserver by chance? Because I've seen the same behaviour. Didn't pay much attention, but curious to know why that happens.

Comment: Nevermind. I see it is. Should probably be added to question: that only happens on `thin`.

Answer (score 20):

I had the exact same error as above.  In my case it was a (.net) client that was attempting to connect to my (thin) server using HTTPS instead of HTTP.  As soon as I changed the protocol back to basic http, the error went away.

Comment: @davidm yes it does work, but the data is not secure, which is a huge problem.

Answer (score 9):

I had visited https://localhost:3000 during a debugging session of rails s -e production, which has config.force_ssl = true.

This forced the latest version of chrome to only attempt to visit https://localhost:3000.com even when I specifically entered http://localhost:3000.

If your application is working in Incognito mode or a different browser. I would suggest clearing your browsing history.

After a binding.pry in the thin server. I was receiving @data encryption of:

```
0\tlocalhost\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x12\x00\x10\x06\x01\x06\x03\x05\x01\x05\x03\x04\x01\x04\x03\x02\x01\x02\x03\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x0E\x00\f\x02h2\bhttp/1.1uP\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\n\x00\b\x00\x06\x00\x1D\x00\x17\x00\x18
```

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue with a thin server.

I threw a binding.pry in thin's request.rb file and found that the following request was causing the error:

```
GET /info?txtAirPlay&txtRAOP RTSP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

It turns out that this could be an issue with Yosemite (I'm running 10.10.3) and the localhost port that you're running. I'm running on port 5000 and if you look at the following stack overflow post, you'll see that Apple AirTunes is running on port 5000:
[AirPlay messes up localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668294/airplay-messes-up-localhost)

Try changing your rails server port to get rid of the error (I just picked 5212 randomly):

```
rails s -p 5212
```

Comment: which variable in request.rb yields `GET /info?txtAirPlay&txtRAOP RTSP/1.0\r\n\r\n`? I'm printing @data and I get a gibberish HTTP Request-like string. Though i tried changing the port, but still wontfix.

Answer (score 4):

1. Are you using `gem thin`
2. If so make sure it's in the right environment in your Gemfile `gem 'thin', group: :development`
3. Else: Try to open http://localhost:3000 on other browsers.... or if you only have only one browser...  you could open an 'incognito' or 'private' window
4. If it's work on other browser then you need to `rake tmp:clear` and clear your browser' cache

Answer (score 3):

In my case this was related to Chrome enforcing HSTS on localhost.  I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817590/673446) to fix:

1. Surf to chrome://net-internals/#hsts
2. In the delete section, enter "localhost" and delete the record from Chrome.

Comment: I was running out of browsers to develop in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you comment it `config.force_ssl = true` and error still apearing - check you request in browser it could be still http**s**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ngrok
First, run development server with ENV as `production` and then execute following command `./ngrok http -bind-tls=true localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome user:

Chrome is enforcing HTTPS instead of HTTP which causes this issue. Click `info icon` next to url and change `Pop-ups and redirects` to `Block` should make it work again.

[image]