# ssl, rails - Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I used to be able to accept HTTPS requests in my local rails server, until after I restarted my machine today. I'm not sure if it's related to the restart or any updates that OSX might have done.

rack says..

```
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    /Users/martinverdejo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@redfire/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
```

I've tried exploring the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614425/invalid-request-invalid-http-format-parsing-fails). But the do not solve the problem.

I tried exploring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30217654/1455717) in particular, running binding pry on thin, and I get a gibberish HTTP request generated. I'm not sure where that comes from:

```
\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA7\x01\x00\x00\xA3\x03\x02\x83#\x7FM\xBBxx\a\x91\xF7\xC3\x10\xF5\xFFq\x8E\xB2\xBD!\xED\x84\x99\xD6\xA4(\xC5\xE9*\x05\x87\xBF:\x00\x00\x10\xC0\n\xC0\x14\xC0\t\xC0\x13\x005\x00/\x00\nV\x00\x01\x00\x00j\xFF\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x18\x00\x00\x15beta.127.0.0.1.xip.io\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x003t\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x14\x00\x12\bspdy/3.1\bhttp/1.1uP\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\n\x00\b\x00\x06\x00\x1D\x00\x17\x00\x18
```

I'm using foreman, my Procfile looks like this.

```
web:    bundle exec rails server -p 3000
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

I tried changing that to the following but it still wontfix.

```
web:    bundle exec thin start -p 3000
web:    bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Any suggestions where else to look?

Comment: That sounds a lot like thin is being run as plain http

Comment: could you please expound on that? @FrederickCheung

Comment: If you haven't run thin with the flags that turn on ssl support then it assumes everything is plain, non encrypted, http.

Comment: '\x16\x03\x01\...' - that gibberish is actually TLS, i.e. the client is doing a HTTPS request but your server assumes HTTP only.

Comment: @FrederickCheung i'm using foreman to start by instance, i'm not sure if the current Procfile handles that, i edited my answer. would you know i can insert the the solution?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i'm assuming i need to explicitly say `thin start --ssl` somewhere, but how do you suggest I do that, given that i start my instance using foreman?

Comment: I tried adding ssl option to thin start but i still get the gibberish

Comment: @MartinVerdejo: I have no idea how to fix your problems, I could only explain what the gibberish means.