# MVC WebApplication no longer starts in IIS Express (redirects to https://localhost in Chrome)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, internet-explorer, https, asp.net-identity

I was changing OAuth/Owin settings and Azure publish settings in a Web Application project this morning, but soon after we decided deployment will be to a specific IIS Azure VM (now visible across our local domain). All code/setting changes have been reverted.

At one point I also changed the `drivers\etc\hosts` file to allow a dummy name for Microsoft OAuth, but that has been reverted.

**Notes:**

- My startup URL is http://localhost:22222/
- I am running under IIS Express (as my local Dev VM will not allow me to install full IIS)
- When I start the Web Application with IE I simply get "This page can't be displayed"
- If I start it with Chrome I get "This webpage is not available", but it also changes the browser URL to https://localhost (note the `s`, i.e. using SSL).
- I have pulled the project down fresh from source control. No change.
- The project is under TFS source control.
- Another developer on the same project has the latest files and it works fine.
- If I run any other Web Application project, they work just fine.
- All OWIN registration of providers has been commented out. No change.
- Deleted the entire project folder and pulled fresh from TFS. No change. This probably means a local machine setting somewhere is the cause?

What could I have damaged in my Web Application to cause this problem? I have been scratching my head for hours now and nothing we try is working. The application simply will not start in any browser.

Project Web Settings tab:

[image]

Comment: Show the screenshot of `Project` => `Properties` => `Web` tab. This probably will explain a lot.

Comment: @trailmax: Added (did not help us, but please do take a look or request further info). Thanks

Comment: When you re-downloaded your source from TFS, did you remove all user settings files? Get the source into another folder and try running there...

Comment: @trailmax: This is a "really big" project, with dozens of libraries. Pulling it down on the same machine won't work with TFS as it is already mapped. We already know if I pull it down on a new machine it will work. Where are the user settings stored?

Comment: OK, don't have to pull down all the files. Shut down VS, remove all `*.user` files from the root folder. Open the solution again and try. Probably will not work - just guessing.

Comment: @trailmax: removed *.user in the related project folder (also had a look in it and the contents just match the options shown in the Web Settings screen-shot). Still no luck. A new Web Project in the same solution works just fine :(

Comment: That's strange. I'm out of options now. Hope somebody else will help...

Comment: See my answer for partial solution.

Comment: Did you guys solve this? I'm having same problem right now

Answer (score 10):

Answer at bottom, given to this chromium issue [[issue 444479]](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444479) helped me:

> Same here - I also believe caused by HSTS - see
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
>
> If you have (developed) any other localhost sites which send a HSTS
>   header...
>
> eg. Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
>   preload
>
> ...then depending on the value of max-age, future requests to
>   localhost will be required to be served over HTTPS.
>
> To get around this, I did the following.
>
> - In the Chrome address bar type "chrome://net-internals/#hsts"
> - At the very bottom of a page is QUERY domain textbox - verify that localhost is known to the browser
> - If it is, DELETE the localhost domain using the textbox above
> - Your site should now work using plain old HTTP
>
> HTH,
>
> Jay
>
> ps. This is not a permanent solution, but will at least get it working
>   between projects. If anyone knows how to permanently exclude localhost
>   from the HSTS list please let me know :)

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, lost almost one hour before finding your answer :)

Comment: Thanks this is awesome. I lost a couple of hours because of this

Comment: @Bogac - Any thought about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34130579/2404470) please?

Comment: Hi! I am also facing the same issue, tried above method but nothing works. localhost is not known to it still it is loading the site on https.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it right? There are 2 textboxes at the bottom in that settings page. One for Query and on top of that Delete. You need to type localhost in Delete Domain textbox and click Delete button.