# ASP.NET MVC website getting redirected to local IIS instead of IIS express on any browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, redirect, iis-express

**Aim:**

Locally run ASP.NET MVC website on IIS express on any browser.

**History:**

The project in concern is an ASP.NET MVC website which initially was setup to use Local IIS with SSL enabled. I tried to set it up on IIS express:

[image: website configuration]

**RouteConfig.cs file**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "_View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**There are 2 redirection possibilities in web.config**

For authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

For error handling

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Error/Error.html" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
```

**Problem:**

Although the above setting is done, the site is getting redirected to Local IIS (https://localhost) instead of IIS express (e.g. http://localhost/12345 or https://localhost/12345).

What is tried so far:

- `Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)` is [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130579/asp-net-mvc-website-getting-redirected-to-local-iis-instead-of-iis-express-on-an#comment56018301_34130579).
- [Added _CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKAROUNDS and repaired IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27155236/2404470)
- [MVC WebApplication no longer starts in IIS Express (redirects to https://localhost in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195505/mvc-webapplication-no-longer-starts-in-iis-express-redirects-to-https-localho)
- Tried [recreating virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34161146/2404470)
- [UrlRewrite is not stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939309/2404470)
- Old [certs are deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818853/2404470)

There is a question mark on the site which inside IIS, this must be [ignorable](https://serverfault.com/a/436619/200629)

[image: multiple procols]

After removing https binding, the redirection is happening however the page seems to be not loading.

[image: https removed]

Visual studio is allowing to debug the `Application_Start()` and `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`. Afterwards, any break point is not hit.

This is happening with all controllers and actions on all browsers.

## Where am I going wrong? or is it some bug?

Comment: Any code that is doing the redirect? When does it happen?

Comment: Do you mean routeconfig?

Comment: Or any other place. When and where does the redirect happen?

Comment: Do you have any redirects in the web config?

Comment: Try checking the "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" option.

Comment: In the first picture you still have selected IIS Express in the Servers section. It should be "Local IIS"

Comment: @PatrickHofman - SSL with IIS Express worked with it's standard port **443**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is the hack behind this...

> To run an ASP.NET MVC website on IIS Express (instead of Local IIS) with SSL enabled, one need to make sure that the 5 digit URL port starts with [**443**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568143/2404470)**xx**

where **xx** can range from 0 to 99

[image: 443xx port]

Now, the **redirection is also not happening**. The website is perfectly running on IIS Express