# Adding SSL to asp mvc wont let me connect to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl

I have made an mvc application and tried adding SSL to it.

The site works fine on http, but when I navigate to the https url, it just says that the site cannot be reached(ERR_CONNECTION_RESET).

I have correct bindings in the (IIS Express) applicationhost.config file.

```
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:3426:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44341:localhost" />
            </bindings>
```

I can see the https in the IISExpress.

I tried starting visual studio as administrator.

I tried disabling and enabling ssl.

I've tried suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress) thread.

Nothing works.

What can be the problem? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you really put the `<bindings>` into the csproj file?? They belong in the [ApplicationHost.config file](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings). SSL is a feature of IIS (or another web server), not a feature of Visual Studio.

Comment: My bad, I meant the applicationhost.config file

Comment: Which applicationHost.config is it? Show the full path. IIS Express or full IIS? Those are the details you should provide. And then you can use Jexus Manager to do some initial troubleshooting, https://jexus.lextudio.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: The IIS Express applicationHost.config. Added to the main post