# MVC HTTPS localhost Chrome connection not secure NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, ssl

I have a website. It has an SSL certificate and I've had no problems until all of a sudden Chrome and Firefox won't accept my self signed certificate for localhost.

I've looked and found a lot of questions on this issue but haven't been able to fix it. Is there a step-by-step guide to fixing this?

I have followed this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818853/853295 but my certificate already has a Friendly Name with correct name.

[Here's an image of my certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRNLh.png)

[image]

Comment: For Chrome you can just tell it to ignore the error. chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: That worked. Thanks for that!! I wish I could vote you up but I'm still too new for that.

Comment: I added it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Chrome you can just tell it to ignore the error. chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: Can this cause any problems or damage or have any detrimental effects?

Comment: Do you know how to fix error for vhosts on localhost too?

Comment: Dov - unless you are navigating to strange localhost sites there is nothing that I know of.

Comment: @suz launch chrome with --ignore-certificate-errors that works on windows only

Comment: I tried this on Chrome v69, and it doesn't work. I restarted my browser and it still didn't work. Has something changed? (This is on a Mac.)