# Visual Studio 2017: Site not reachable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Am not able to run VS 2015 mvc project in VS 2017 successfully. It gives the following error in the output window and runs alright:

> code:-32000 message:No script for id: 32

If say the MVC project url is set to something like: https://localhost:36725 . When navigating to the same url, it says `This site can’t be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: It's about certification problem on your computer, you can ignore it. Just debug your program on localhost with SSL error. When you deploy your project to real server, it won't be like your localhost.

Comment: The problem is not SSL I think as I can't even view the website when I navigate to the url. It just says This site can’t be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: I believe that it's related with IIS Express SSL certification issue. If you set "false" SSL Enabled attribute of project properties, you can reach the website. Please find out more from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress

Answer (score 1):

This is because the port number you specified for SSL is not in the range of 44300 to 44399 (i.e. the standard SSL 443 followed by any two digits).  This is built into the default localhost certificates that Visual Studio will install for you as trusted root certs.

You can either change the port to be within this range (don't forget to create the virtual directory), or you can add an additional port for your desired port number using "netsh http add sslcert" from the command line.

See the solution with 200+ upvotes here:

[SSL Connection / Connection Reset with IISExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress)