# How to enable SSL in Telerik Reporting CORS REST Service

Tags: rest, cors, telerik, reporting

I am trying to enable SSL in a Telerik Reporting CORS REST Service. It is a .Net Framework 4.7 REST Api. Here's the screenshot of the error reflected in the [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aXJ2.jpg).

I think I have a similar situation explained [here](https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/18/how-to-enable-ssl-for-a-net-project-in-visual-studio/), however my certificate was already trusted and adding it to the Root didn't solve the problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My issue was related to IIS Express. Uninstalling it and installing it back fixed the problem. Thanks a lot to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress/22818853#22818853).