# What defines the category of output window where message will be shown?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, logging, nservicebus, serilog

I have a default asp.net core application from API template.
I write log message in GetWeatherForecast action and I see the message both in `Debug` and `LoggingTests - ASP.NET Core Web Server` categories of output window (Show output from).

[image]

Yet messages logged by NServcieBus message handler are shown only in `Debug`.

I'd expect that section `LoggingTests - ASP.NET Core Web Server` just shows all the messages coming form the same process, however, NServiceBus case disproves this assumption.

When you start multiple applications with IIS Express profile you do not have console output, and `Debug` shows output from any of these apps. This is quite annoying. I was looking for the messages to be grouped under the corresponding section, but as I said, messages from NServiceBus do not arrive there.

Does anyone know what are the criteria for the message to be shown in `ASP.NET Core Server` section?

Comment: Are you using the NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting extension? If yes have you upgraded to 1.1.0 already? That package provides first party integration with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging for NServiceBus

Comment: @DanielMarbach No difference. But the log messages are coming from hosted service.

Comment: Ok then your question is more related to ASP.NET Core and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging configuration I guess. From an NServiceBus perspective when you have that extension everything should be properly setup to use the MS logging infrastructure

Comment: @DanielMarbach Again and again I am stepping on the same rake. The issue was caused that when no browser is launched, IIS Express does not start the host even if  hosted service is registered. And if browser is launched, and HTTPS url is defined, port must be withing [44300-44398 range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress/24957146#24957146).

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm probably not much help here since this is not exactly my area of expertise