# ASP.NET MVC - IIS Express (Google Chrome)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Starting new  Visual Studio project from scratch, ASP.NET MVC.

By running the web with F5 (IIS Express) google chrome i get an error:

[image: Error]

So far only thing i've changed (or should i say added) is 2 classes in Models folder (Student and University), 1 class in ViewModels folder  (StudentUneiversityViewModel) and added a blank form of StudentController to Controllers.

Note that i tried creating new blank project and the error is still the same. Cant run with IIS Express. Also, i can somehow run my friend's project that he sent me, without a problem. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: The following post may provide help -- I am NOT referring to the **accepted answer** but rather the answer that has 380 or more upvotes and was awarded the +200 bounty -- the answer refers to PORT number configuration for IIS Express: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress

Comment: @Alex - And what URL was passed to the Google Chrome?

Comment: @Jackdaw it was localhost/port. Even if i try to go manually to localhost/port/home it still doesnt work

Comment: @Alex - The URL format is `http://localhost:port/home`. Change `/` after `localhost` to colon. I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: @DavidTansey I tried this, changing port in project properties. Still the same. Not sure what causes this.

Comment: @Jackdaw Unfortunately all that does is google search for 'http://localhost:port:home.

Comment: This could be caused by a number of things. Does it work with IE? Does it work with FF? Do you have a local firewall installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Solution properties > Web > Servers

Under servers there is project url field. It was https://localhost:44328/ and
all i had to do is change `https` to `http`.