# IIS Express SSL ERR CONECTION RESET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express, iis-express-10

I have a W10 x64 workstation that's having trouble making SSL work on IIS Express

I've tried every posible solution that I've seen on this site and others, still haven't found a solution

The most close I was, I was able to run the IIS Express command that setups an SLL site on port 443 for localhost using the self signed param, it wasn't working in the Program Files (x86) folder, when I'd ran the command, it throws an error saying something like "there's already a file"

But on the Folder Program Files (the x64 one), I was able to run the command once, and started working... for one day at least, the other day the ERR CONECTION RESET happened again, and this time when I tried running the command again from the x64 folder, this time it said the same error, that "already a file" error

Also when I run netsh show sslcert -> file.txt, there an error that says someting like "could'd find the file"

Tried Jexus Manager, and when I go to HTTP API, it throws the same error ^^, and brings nothing and another error saying Null exception

I tried reinstalling IIS Express 10 several times, the certificate is in place and the dialog to trust it shows, yet the ERR CONECTION RESET keeps happening

I have VS 2017 installed

Comment: [As documented](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html) you can use `netsh http show sslcert` at command prompt to analyze what part has corrupted in Windows HTTP API. Once you manually fix that, Jexus Manager and other tools should start to work again.

Comment: @LexLi when I run netsh http show sslcert it throws this error: SSL Certificate bindings:
-------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread? Similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417219/ssl-connection-connection-reset-with-iisexpress

Comment: @JennyDai yes, I have followed every solution there is, and still having the same problem

Comment: As Lex Li said, you should fix the error thrown by the SSL certificate first.